# How to quantify differences between groups of vectors using linear regression?

Tags: r, regression, multivariate-analysis, lm

I have two groups of spectra, that could be viewed as a vectors with each wn corresponding to the vector's component. I'd like to quantify the difference between these two groups, and I tried to use linear model to express one group of vectored values as a function of the other vector values. So, I used lm function in R, but I don't know if I applied it correctly and how to make sense of it.

Here is the function:

> summary(lm(spectra_group1 ~ spectra_group2))

For each vector within a group1 it gives a corresponding output:

[image]

I guess, it treats each spectrum as a $y_i$, in this instance, but in each spectrum there are over 3000 variables. So, I don't understand how it can reduce all these variables to just one $y_i$. Furthermore, in this example, there are several spectrum ( III, IX, XI - XIII) that have p-values significantly low. That would indicate, that they are correlated to the group1$spectrum_x. I would be glad, if someone could assist with ideas how to develop a method to quantify the differences between groups, possibly with some linear model. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Ordinarily one views a spectrum as a *function* (or as its Fourier transform) and employs a functional norm, such as a weighted $L^p$ norm, to measure how close two spectra may be.  The choice of the norm depends on what your spectra mean and why you are comparing them. `lm` is not going to accomplish any of this for you.  Thus, pursuing this question is likely going to be a dead end (or worse, will lead you astray).

Comment: @whuber Ok, but that's just a way to measure a difference between two individual spectrums. But what a statistical method that can estimate the difference between groups?

Comment: Statistics doesn't tell you how to compare spectra: physics does.  Given a metric and a model for the variation within a spectra you will consider as "random" or inconsequential, statistics can help you decide whether to view two spectra as different or not.  *You* need to supply that metric.